# NullReferenceException when accessing static ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a program for my Windows Phone class and I hit a bit of a problem. When I try to fire up the application, I get a null reference exception when trying to access a static ObservableCollection. I thought that because it was static, I didn't need to instantiate it. Am I doing something wrong here? Here's the method:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    this.DataContext = null;
    this.DataContext = Settings.NotesList;
    Settings.CurrentNoteIndex = -1;
    TheListBox.SelectedIndex = -1;
    if (Settings.NotesList.Count <= 0) // EXCEPTION
    {
        NoteStatus.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
        TheListBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    else
    {
        NoteStatus.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
        TheListBox.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Where in a separate file I have:

```
public static class Settings
{
    static Settings() { }
    public static ObservableCollection<Note> NotesList;
    static IsolatedStorageSettings settings;
    private static int currentNoteIndex;
    public static int CurrentNoteIndex { get; set; }
}
```

I wanted to test the program before writing any more but I'm not sure what's causing this. The OnNavigatedTo is from launching the application so I never even get to MainPage.xaml. Help is very appreciated.

Comment: Why dont you do NotesList = new ObservableCollection<Note>() in the static ctor?

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks, I'm fairly new to C#.

Comment: So it wasn't the Settings class you needed to instantiate, it was the NotesList property of that class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even through its static, it still needs to be instantiate somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, Johan pointed me in the right direction and I instantiated it in the constructor.

Comment: @derekwolf I am curious to know how did you instantiate the static class in constructor?

Comment: @dotNETbeginner, no, he instantiated an `ObservableCollection` inside a static constructor.